# In R, subset a dataframe on rows whose ID appears more than once

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**Background**

I have a dataframe `d` with ~10,000 rows and *n* columns, one of which is an `ID` variable. Most `ID`'s  appear once, but some appear more than once. Say that it looks like this:

[image: d]

**Problem**

I'd like a new dataframe `d_sub` which only contains `ID`'s that appear more than once in `d`. I'd like to have something that looks like this:

[image: d_sub]

**What I've tried**

I've tried something like this:

```
d_sub <- subset(d, duplicated(d$ID))
```

But that only gets me one entry for `ID`'s `b` and `d`, and I want *each* of their respective rows:

[image: failed_attempt]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to change the `duplicated` with `|` condition as `duplicated` by itself is FALSE for the first occurrence of 'ID'

```
d_sub <- subset(d, duplicated(ID)|duplicated(ID, fromLast = TRUE))
```

Comment: This works, but I can't quite tell from the documentation on `duplicated` just *why* it works. What exactly is `fromLast` doing? ("duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE) is equivalent to but faster than rev(duplicated(rev(x)))" --> Greek to me)

Comment: @logjammin just take a simple example. `v1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3); duplicated(v1); duplicated(v1, fromLast = TRUE)` the `fromLast = TRUE`, does the duplicate from the reverse.  when you do `|`, any of the corresponding TRUE values becomes TRUE and thus all the elements with duplicates are TRUE, now

Comment: @logjammin depends on the function i.e. `rev` may have some additioinal checks that prevent it from being faster. whereas if you use a single function i.e. `duplicated` all those checks are already done

Comment: Oh I see, that's interesting. Side thought: not complaining by any means but it seems odd that this would need to be done with an `OR` condition -- seems like `R` would be able to do this more succinctly. Anyways thanks a ton!

Comment: @logjammin `duplicated` is an old function.  You are right that it should be able to have this option inherently to avoid calling `duplicated` twice

Answer (score 2):

We could use `add_count`, then filter on `n`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    add_count(ID) %>% 
    filter(n!=1) %>%
    select(-n)
```

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
    ~ID, ~gender, ~zip,
    "a", "f", 1,
    "b", "f", NA,
    "b", "m", 2,
    "c", "f", 3,
    "d", "f", NA,
    "d", "m", 4)

df %>%
    add_count(ID) %>% 
    filter(n!=1) %>%
    select(-n)
```

Output:

```
  ID    gender   zip
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 b     f         NA
2 b     m          2
3 d     f         NA
4 d     m          4
```